# How to solve "syntax error at line 1 "

Tags: regex, syntax-error, yacc, lex

Hi I've used lex and yacc to create my own programming language syntax (sort of) , but no matter how my grammar rules are put , it gives me syntax error at the same first line.

This is my lex code of regular expressions:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%option noyywrap
punct [.]
virgula [,]
numar [0-9]+
numar2 [0-9] 
%% 
"&librarie=>" {return INCLUDE;}
"stringuri"|"vectori"|"mape"|"matematica" {return LIBRARII;}
"intreg"|"caracter"|"string"|"natural" {return TIPVAR;}
"real" {return REAL;}
"daca" {return DACA;}
"pentru" {return PENTRU;}
"cat_timp" {return CATTIMP;}
def_variabla_globala {return VARGLOBALE;}
def_variabla_locala {return VARLOCALE;}
structura_obiect {return STRUCTURA;}
"procedura[]" {return PROCEDURA;}
start_program {return START;}
stop_program {return STOP;}
inceput_bloc_if {return INBLOCIF;}
sfarsit_bloc_if {return SFBLOCIF;}
atunci {return ATUNCI;}
altfel {return ALTFEL;}
from {return FROM;}
to {return TO;}
smaller_than {return MAIMIC;}
greater_than {return MAIMARE;}
equal_to {return EGAL;}
different_than {return DIFERIT;}
inceput_bloc_for {return INBLOCFOR;}
sfarsit_bloc_for {return SFBLOCFOR;}
inceput_bloc_cat_timp {return INBLOCCATTIMP;}
sfarsit_bloc_cat_timp {return SFBLOCCATTIMP;}
executa {return EXECUTA;}
suma {return SUM;}
invers {return INV;}
oglindit {return OGL;}
"<-" {return ASIGNARE;}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {return ID;REJECT;}
{numar} {return NUMAR;REJECT;}
[0-9]{punct}{numar} {return NUMARREAL;}
{numar}|({virgula}{numar})* {return VECTASIGN;}
({numar2}{punct}{numar})|({virgula}({numar2}{punct}{numar}))* {return VECTASIGNREAL;}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]* {return CUVANT;REJECT;}
afisare {return AFISARE;}
[ \t] ;
\n {yylineno++;}
. {return yytext[0];}
%%
```

I used `REJECT` at those 2 regex , because it gave me a warning , several of my rules were having conflicts with each other.

My grammar rules :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

extern FILE* yyin;
extern char* yytext;
extern int yylineno;
%}
%token INCLUDE LIBRARII ID TIPVAR CUVCHEIE REAL NUMARREAL FROM TO VECTASIGNREAL VARGLOBALE VARLOCALE VECTASIGN STRUCTURA PROCEDURA START STOP DACA PENTRU CATTIMP INBLOCIF SFBLOCIF ATUNCI ALTFEL MAIMIC MAIMARE EGAL DIFERIT INBLOCFOR SFBLOCFOR INBLOCCATTIMP SFBLOCCATTIMP EXECUTA SUM INV OGL ASIGNARE NUMAR CUVANT AFISARE
%start progr
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%
progr: headere declaratii program {printf("correct syntax");}
     ;

headere :   header
        |headere header 
        ;

header : INCLUDE LIBRARII
       ;

declaratii : declaratie ';'
           | declaratii declaratie ';'
           ;

declaratie : VARGLOBALE TIPVAR ID 
           | VARGLOBALE TIPVAR ID '[' NUMAR ']'
           | VARGLOBALE TIPVAR ID ASIGNARE NUMAR
           | VARGLOBALE TIPVAR ID ASIGNARE '#' CUVANT '#' 
           | VARGLOBALE TIPVAR ID '[' NUMAR ']' ASIGNARE '[' VECTASIGN ']'
           | VARGLOBALE REAL ID
           | VARGLOBALE REAL ID '[' NUMAR ']'
           | VARGLOBALE REAL ID ASIGNARE NUMARREAL
           | VARGLOBALE REAL ID '[' NUMAR ']' ASIGNARE '[' VECTASIGNREAL ']'
           ;

program : PROCEDURA START bloc STOP
        ;

bloc : declaratiile instructiuni
     ;

declaratiile : declaratia ';'
           | declaratiile declaratia ';'
           ;

declaratia : VARLOCALE TIPVAR ID 
           | VARLOCALE TIPVAR ID '[' NUMAR ']'
           | VARLOCALE TIPVAR ID ASIGNARE NUMAR
           | VARLOCALE TIPVAR ID ASIGNARE '#' CUVANT '#' 
           | VARLOCALE TIPVAR ID '[' NUMAR ']' ASIGNARE '[' VECTASIGN ']'
           | VARLOCALE REAL ID
           | VARLOCALE REAL ID '[' NUMAR ']'
           | VARLOCALE REAL ID ASIGNARE NUMARREAL
           | VARLOCALE REAL ID '[' NUMAR ']' ASIGNARE '[' VECTASIGNREAL ']'
           ;
instructiuni : instructiune ';'
             | instructiuni instructiune ';'
             ;

instructiune : instructiune_simpla ';'
             | instructiune_compusa ';'
             ;

instructiune_simpla : ID ASIGNARE expresie ';'
                    ;

expresie : expresie '+' expresie 
         | expresie '-' expresie 
         | expresie '*' expresie 
         | expresie '/' expresie 
         | functie 
         | NUMAR 
         | ID
         ;

functie : INV '(' expresie ')' 
        | SUM '(' expresie ',' expresie ',' expresie ',' expresie ',' expresie ')'
        | OGL '(' expresie ')' 
        | AFISARE '(' NUMAR ')' 
        | AFISARE '(' ID ')'    
        | AFISARE '(' CUVANT ')' 
        ;
instructiune_compusa : DACA conditie ATUNCI
                      INBLOCIF
                      instructiuni
                      SFBLOCIF
                      ALTFEL
                      INBLOCIF
                      instructiuni
                      SFBLOCIF
                     |PENTRU ID FROM NUMAR TO NUMAR EXECUTA
                      INBLOCFOR
                      instructiuni
                      SFBLOCFOR
                     |CATTIMP ID conditie NUMAR
                     INBLOCCATTIMP
                     instructiuni
                     SFBLOCCATTIMP
                     ;
conditie : MAIMARE
         | MAIMIC
         | EGAL
         ;

%%
int yyerror(char * s){
printf("error: %s line:%d\n",s,yylineno);
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv){
yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
yyparse();
}
```

And this is the file that I test with , and it should return that the program has a correct syntax.

```
&librarie=>stringuri
&librarie=>vectori

def_variabila_globala intreg var1<-23;
def_variabila_globala natural vect[50]<-{1,3,51,2,421,12,43};
def_variabila_globala real a<-12.5;
def_variabila_globala caracter ch<-#x#;
def_variabila_globala string s<-#alabala portocala#;

structura_obiect persoana
~
real inaltime;
natural varsta;
~

procedura[]
start_program

def_variabila_locala intreg negativ,pozitiv,s,contor1,contor2<-5;
def_variabila_locala adunari_scaderi;
def_variabila_locala inmultiri_impartiri;
def_variabila_locala ad_scd_inm_imp;
persoana p1;

p1@inaltime<-1.82;
p1@varsta<-20;
adunari_scaderi<-243-12+43-12+11+31-124;
afisare<adunari_scaderi>;

inmultiri_impartiri<-3*4/2/2*3/9;
afisare<inmultiri_impartiri>;

ad_scd_inm_imp<-4*2-3+5/2*5;
afisare<ad_scd_inm_imp>;

negativ<-invers<2>;
afisare<negativ>;

daca(invers<inmultiri_impartiri> smaller_than 0) 
antunci
inceput_bloc_if
pentru contor1 from 0 to 10 executa
inceput_bloc_for
afiseaza<#for1#>;
afiseaza<#for2#>;
sfarsit_bloc_for
sfarsit_bloc_if
altfel
inceput_bloc_if
afiseaza<#if#>;
sfarsit_bloc_if

cat_timp contor2 greater_than 0 
inceput_bloc_cat_timp
afisare<#cattimp#>;
contor<-contor-1;
sfarsit_bloc_cat_timp

pozitiv<-invers<-2>;
afisare<pozitiv>;

var1<-oglindit<321>;
afisare<var1>;

s<-suma<1,3,12,31,oglindit<123-2>>;
afisare<s>;

afisare<#ProgramTerminat#>;

stop_program
```

I don't know where it could be wrong , is because of the lexical rules , are they interfering with each other?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

**error mesage** : `error: syntax error at line:1`
**The exact problem is that the parser sees a non valid rule at my `"&librarie=>stringuri"` declaration , in my file. (line 1)**

Comment: Is this homework? also please post exact error, and try to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Hi , I've edited my question and no , it's a personal project for practical purposes.

Comment: Not reproducible here, the first error is on line 4 because of the misspelling variabila/variabla.

Comment: @n.m. Yes indeed , I feel embarassed , however when I compile I still get the error at line 1 :( ; it's like yylineno's value is always 1.

Comment: Perhaps you have a line ending issue (msdos vs unix) in the source file.